# how to use facebook Sharing audiences API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

how to use facebook Sharing audiences API ?

---

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts
```

i have tried running it in graph api explorer i didn't understand what are the attributes need to be supply and usage.

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#sharing)? What problem specifically did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this it works fine!

---

```
     import requests
     import json

     params = {'access_token': 'youraccess_token' ,'adaccounts': [youraddaccount]}

     r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts', data=params)

     print r.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

the Facebook Ads API call for sharing your audiences would be something like this:

```
Add's Ad Account Ids provided in the below call
HTTP POST: https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts/

Post Params:
'adaccounts' = array('adActId1','adActId2')

Delete Ad Accounts from the Audience with below call
HTTP DELETE: https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts
```

Refer: [View This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Success result using postman

[image]

> It only worked when adding access token to url, not worked when adding
>   access token to post body.